# Need help in editing .lnk files?

Tags: shortcut

I have been searching for a solution to a problem and came across a post answered by JasonMArcher and wonder if I could be more specific as to my needs.

We have recently changed to a new server and because of a change in it's name from //sbcmaster to //sbcserver1 I have a huge problem where I have hundreds of .lnk files need to be edited so that the shortcut retrieves the document.

The question is - Is it possible to automate this process?

Appreciation in advance!!

Mark

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe you can search and replace the values and see if it works

Comment: This probably doesn't help in your case, but one piece of advice I got on another forum a long time ago that I've taken to heart is using .url files for doing links instead of platform specific link files like .lnk this would have made your life much easier

Answer (score 3):

If you use run/cmd you can edit the filename (with rename). Then a friendly editor like Notepad++ will open that file. You can see the text, and there will also be a lot of NULLs. You can edit the text. Then you can save the file, and then change the name back with rename. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to create or install any apps, I just wanted a script that would update target paths internal to a folder structure. For instance, update internal shortcuts after moving `C:\ProjectFoo` to `C:\Projects\Foo`.  I found a [solution](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-change-shortcut-lnk-targets-in-bulk-using-script/) at winhelponline that gives an example powershell script.

1. Create the script in, e.g.,  `C:\_sandbox\lnk_change.ps1`:

```
$oldPrefix  = "C:\ProjectFoo"     # Path prefix to replace
$newPrefix  = "C:\Projects\Foo"   # New path prefix
$searchPath = "C:\Projects\Foo"   # Where to search for links
$shell = new-object -com wscript.shell
write-host "Updating shortcut target" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor black
dir $searchPath -filter *.lnk -recurse | foreach {
  $lnk = $shell.createShortcut( $_.fullname )
  $oldPath= $lnk.targetPath
  $lnkRegex = "^" + [regex]::escape( $oldPrefix )
  if ( $oldPath -match $lnkRegex ) {
    $newPath = $oldPath -replace $lnkRegex, $newPrefix
    write-host "Found: " + $_.fullname -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
    write-host " Replace: " + $oldPath
    write-host " With: " + $newPath
    $lnk.targetPath = $newPath
    $lnk.Save()
  }
}
```

2. Enter in the run box (`Win+R`):

```
powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\_sandbox\lnk_change.ps1
```

3. The PowerShell window remains open to allow scrutiny of the resulting activity.

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft documentation for Shell Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) points to the [`IShellLink::GetPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`IShellLink::SetPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

Comment: I have tried using UltraEdit to see whether it is possible to search and replace the occurance of the old server... but unfortunately as son as you try and 'edit' the .lnl file the system tries to open the short cut!! So it is impossible to get at the file... Any suggestions?

Comment: Goto cmd and give the command edit <filename>.lnk ; but it is more difficult to edit this from cmd. I think taking this file to a linux computer and opening it in a hex editor would be a better idea; however I'm not sure if linux recognises .lnk as shortcut as well

Comment: To edit a `.lnk` file in Notepad (for example), you can use either Start, Run or run this in CMD/Powershell: `Notepad "C:\Users\user\Desktop\shortcut.lnk"`

Answer (score 0):

The utility [Shortcuts Search And Replace](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/ShortcutsSearchAndReplace/) can be used for that.

It allows to find .lnk files and to replace their target name or path.